# Laravel 5.7 and Vue router mode

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I have an application on development phase and I tried adding Vuejs. Now I want to remove the hash # in the URL. In the vue-router instance I added the routes and tried to add the

```
<code>mode:history</code>
```

but it doesn't work. Any Idea on how to solve this? Thanks

Here's my routes

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Appearance from './components/Appearance/Appearance.vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

let routes =  [
    {path: '/appearance', component: Appearance}
]

const router = new VueRouter([
    routes

])


Vue.component('Sidebar', require('./components/_partials/Sidebar.vue'));


const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router
});
```

Comment: Please share the code. The `web.php` & `routes.js`

Answer (score 4):

In routes configuration you need to change it to be like this:

```
const router = new VueRouter([
    mode: 'history', // Add this line
    routes
]);
```

And in your web routes located in your-app-path/routes/web.php you need to change it to be like this:

```
Route::get('/{any}', 'AppearanceController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

With these base config you will be able to enable the html5 history mode. Now you can navigate to any page and you can even refresh the page where you are and you will still where you are. hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Add **hashbang** and **history** in router configuration which will remove # in the URL

Try this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  hashbang: false, // Add this line
  history: true, // Add this line
  routes
})
```

Comment: AddWeb: we had some conversations over the years, in which I pointed out that succinctness is valued here, and boilerplate sign-offs and chatty material are discouraged and removed. A moderator agreed with this, and upheld an edit I made on one of your questions, and you have kindly refrained from adding this for at least a year.

Comment: Please continue to refrain - everyone hopes their material helps, and no-one posts hoping their material does not help. It is redundant, and this is not a chat-room. Thanks!